# WEBPACK - How do i require prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, webpack, prototype, webpack-2

I am have just recently started looking at **Webpack** as a module loader for future jQuery plugins, but i am running into a problems when trying to separate individual prototype functions in separate files. **Webpack** appears to be importing the prototype functions into separate IFFEs which in turn give me an console error.

Is there something fundamental i am doing wrong?

**Example code:** (before running webpack)

*app.js*

```
function() {


    var Cars = function(color, doors, year, make) {
        this.color = color;
        this.doors = doors;
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
    }

    require('./imports/module1.js');

    var Audi = new Cars("red", 5, 2001, "Audi");

    Audi.listing();    

})();
```

*module1.js*

```
// Module 1
console.log("Module 1");

Cars.prototype.listing = function() {
        console.log(this.year + ", " + this.color + ", " + this.make + ", with " + this.doors + " doors");
}
```

**WEBPACK snippit**

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// Module 1
console.log("Module 1");

Cars.prototype.listing = function() {
        console.log(this.year + ", " + this.color + ", " + this.make + ", with " + this.doors + " doors");
}

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {


(function() {


    var Cars = function(color, doors, year, make) {
        this.color = color;
        this.doors = doors;
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
    }

    __webpack_require__(0);

    var Audi = new Cars("red", 5, 2001, "Audi");

    Audi.listing();



})();


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

**Console ERROR**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cars is not defined
    at Object.make.color (module1.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 91cca6f…:19)
    at app.js:12
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 91cca6f…:19)
    at bootstrap 91cca6f…:65
    at bootstrap 91cca6f…:65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems in your code:

1. Your `module1` is not a real module which depends on an undeclared variable `Car`. That's why error reported.
2. Also `module1` tries to make a side effect on `Cart`(aka adding one more attribute on Car's prototype) which is not a good practice. It's ok to make side effect, but better to set it explicitly when needed, instead via module loading.
3. In `Cars` module, it's better to treat the `require` part as a static one, instead of a method of taking some effect. (See this ref: http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#es6-modules)

Suggested improvements and fix:

```
// module 1
module.exports = {
  list: function list() { /* .... */ }
}

// Cars

// require, no effect;
var module1 = require('./module1')
function Cars() {
  // code
}

// Take effect. via extending. I used underscore, you can use whatever    extending methods such as $.extend
_.extend(Cars.prototype, module1}

//....other code
```

Also IFFE is not needed in module in fact, you can get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks this makes alot more sense. Two questions, when referring to the .extend method, do you mean the jQuery method or does webpack have it's own extend method? Also you mention IFFE, my plan was to use webpack with my jQuery plugins. Currently i use the jQuery boilert plate patter and that relies on IFFE to limit scope.

Comment: My pleasure @FrederickM.Rogers. For extend I meant this one http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ which basically add/overwrite attributes from one object to original. For IFFE, it's not needed in webpack, basically IFFE aims to run code once which means same thing as requiring a module. If all plugins are yours, you can write it as the object way and extend all of them in once place which would be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you again, i will have a go and see how it turns out.